# Launch a WebWorker in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, web-worker

I am struggling in order to launch a Protractor test in an Angular application.

Here's the project architecture :

- build
- dist

  - app
  - tests

    - e2e

      - my-test.js
- lib

  - some librairies, including the vortex-web library
- main

  - css

    - some less files
  - res

    - some assets (img)
    - src
    - my app sources (.ts files)
    - tests
    - e2e

      - my-test.ts
    - definition
    - d.ts files, including vortex-web-client.d.ts file

The problem is that the library I want to include uses Web Workers and Protractor runs in a node environment. I tried a lot of node modules : 
web-worker
webworker-threads
webworkify
worker-component
node-webworker

But none of them seems to work correctly in my case.

My tests scripts are compiled in es5.1, commonjs.

Any help would be very appreciated before I lose my sanity.

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Protractor doesn't run in a node environment per se, it launches a browser (like Chrome, FireFox or PhantomJS), where your tests are run. The browser is driven by selenium (embeded in protractor)

Comment: @Kamo "The problem is that the library I want to include uses Web Workers and Protractor runs in a node environment." => So is there a way to do so, or should I forget my dream to include an external library in a Protractor test ?

Comment: @topheman : even if it launches a browser, the library I want to include cannot work because it launches Web Workers.

Comment: @nugetchar Please show how you include library, spawn a Web Worker and the library name,